# When deploying HP workstations with MAAS I get screen "RCO/USBR boot failed"

Tags: maas, bios

Here is the screen:

[image: screen]

If I start up the machine or deploy it with MAAS I have to press esc to continue boot and get deployed. But when its not connected to a screen or keyboard it won't work because it gets stuck on this screen. I have turned off boot from USB in BIOS and don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been encountering the same problem. I haven't dug into it in a lot of detail, but I was able to workaround this problem by ***disabling USB Redirection support*** in the BIOS Setup configuration for Remote Management.

On this model, the option was in the BIOS Setup; it may be in the Intel AMT (MEBx) Firmware setup on other models? The specific details of where to make the change will vary across workstation models and BIOS versions, but that should point you in the right direction.

Obviously that solution is insufficient if you need the USB redirection, but hopefully (likely) you don't...

I assume this answer is a bit late for you, but it might come in handy for someone else.